# How to convert a MySQL query to JSON on C#

Tags: c#, mysql, json, visual-studio

Here's my code

I want to know how can i show the follow query on JSON format in C# touse it in a Web Service

```
    public void GetEmpleadoJSON()
    {
        string server = "localhost", database = "ventas", user = "root", pass = "";
        MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=" + server + "; database=" + database + "; Uid=" + user + "; pwd=" + pass + ";");
        conectar.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = conectar.CreateCommand();

        //consulta select
        command.CommandText = ("SELECT `nombre` FROM `cliente` WHERE id_cliente=901 ");
        command.Connection = conectar;
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        Empleado[] emps = new Empleado[] {
        new Empleado(){
            Id=101,
            Name=reader.ToString(),
            Salary=10000
        }

    };
       JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(emps));
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can used Newtonsoft.Json to convert your output to JSON format.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public void GetEmpleadoJSON()
    {
        string server = "localhost", database = "ventas", user = "root", pass = "";
        MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=" + server + "; database=" + database + "; Uid=" + user + "; pwd=" + pass + ";");
        conectar.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = conectar.CreateCommand();

        //consulta select
        command.CommandText = ("SELECT `nombre` FROM `cliente` WHERE id_cliente=901 ");
        command.Connection = conectar;
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        Empleado[] emps = new Empleado[] {
    new Empleado(){
        Id=101,
        Name=reader.ToString(),
        Salary=10000
    }

};
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emps);
        Context.Response.Write(jsonString);
    }
```